# Android device getting crashed for on reading the logcat to display

Tags: java, android

I trying to read and display logcat logs of wpa_supplicant below is the code that I am trying to use

```
try {

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat wpa_supplicant:V *:S"); 

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                log.append(line); 
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            process.destroy();

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logData);
            tv.setText(log.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "something went wrong");

        }
```

When I run this in the activity onCreate method, I am getting an error in the logcat saying

**Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'**

When I open that file by pulling from adb it does not have any information
Also my device stops working and it does not respond.

I also checked the exception, unfortunately it is not throwing any exception at all.

Can anybody please help me understand why my device is getting crashed if I run this above code, I am just reading the logcat log and displaying it in the textview.

Please note, that I have permissions set in my manifest to read logs

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing the `process.destroy();`. Is it intended to stop the logging process ? I see this is the reason of app being crashed

Comment: And also remember to add permission in  your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`

Comment: I thought to destroy since it was crashing my device, I actually didn't had it in my code,

Comment: I have added the permission

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I have this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> in my manifest

Comment: add the super user permission too, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />`

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Let me check please wait

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Sorry didn't work, it is still getting crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, the command

```
logcat wpa_supplicant:V *:S
```

is a never ending process, so the device use to run out of memory, I tried using asynch task it works now.

I am posting this to help others who arrive at this post after facing the same problem.